# Javascript anonymous function question

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have this js class which has an anonymous function to retrieve some query results. Since the function which handles the results is anonymous I can't save the results in a this.var variable and use them somewhere else since this in the anonymous function references to the window object. I can't return it as a function return either so how do I do with those results to have them available somewhere else?

```
someObject = {
    //  this.db is created, no need to paste that code
    dbGetAnimals: function () {
        this.db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM animals", function(tx, results){
                return results;
            } )
        });
    },
    printAllAnimals: function () {
        var animals = this.dbGetAnimals();
        alert (animals);//  undefined
    }
}

someObject.printAllAnimals();
```

Comment: dooooont send sql from a javascript call, that opens you up to a lot of attacks.

Comment: web storage mate. learn before posting lol:http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/?todo=sddf

Answer (score 4):

You can create a local variable to hold your `this` reference. Your anonymous function will become a closure, so it will be able to see that local var.

```
dbGetAnimals: function () {
    var myself = this;
    this.db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM animals", function(tx, results){
            myself.var = results;
        } )
    });
},
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it. But I think it's ugly. If I need a callback to execute within a context, I just bind the context using a lib. If you're not using a lib, this is the way to go. See http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind for a thorough description of the problem

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do traditional synchronous/non-blocking programming where you want to do asynchronous programming.

```
var someObject = function()({
    this.dbGetAnimals = function (callback) {
        db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
             tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM animals", function(tx, results){
                 callback(results);
            } )
        });
    },

    this.printAllAnimals = function (callback) {
        this.dbGetAnimals(callback);
    }
})();

someObject.printAllAnimals(function(animals) {
    alert(animals);
}
```

There are much cleaner ways to do this, but for async programming you have to learn to do everything on callbacks instead of direct returns.

Comment: I will explain you my situation to see why this is a big issue. I'm building a small ExtJs application with a grid inside of it. So first I have a ExtJS window then I add a Grid to that window. Grid requires the items to display something. With this type of requests and callbacks hassle it's impossible to simply return the values for the grid to use them. I must create the transaction and inside the transaction build the window and the grid. In your example 'animals' is still trapped inside the callback function of 'printAllAnimals'. I created a full example at http://pastebin.com/3a8GQG8F.

Comment: You can insert that in a html page and watch for the local storage using chrome developer tools. As you can see from the example, alert(animals) returns undefined all the time so how do I do about using that result outside the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the anonymous function in `executeSql` is a callback function which is not executed until the query compmetes, which by definition will be after `dbGetAnimals` returns.  That's why your call to `dbGetAnimals` is returning undefined.

You'll have to pass a callback function to receive the query resutls from within the `executSql` callback:

```
someObject = {  
    //  this.db is created, no need to paste that code  
    dbGetAnimals: function (callback) {  
        this.db.readTransaction(function(tx) {  
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM animals", function(tx, results){  
                callback(results);
            } );
        });  
    },  
    printAllAnimals: function () {  
        this.dbGetAnimals(function(animals) {
            alert(animals)
        });  
    }  
}  


someObject.printAllAnimals();
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: animals is not defined

Comment: @Tim: Oh duh.  That code had the same problem you had -- the `alert()` would run before the query actually ran.  I've fixed the code above.

Comment: ok but this still doesn't save my problem. While alert() function might work inside that callback function I have no way of making the "animals" available to the rest of the class. How do I make 'printAllAnimals', when called, return the 'animals' inside the object itself?

Comment: @Tim: The design of sample code above assumes that you want `dbGetAnimals` to always simply return a fresh copy of the resultset.  You could do `someObject.dbGetAnimals(function(result) { someObject.animals = result; });` to make the cached resultset publically available.